# CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider error "No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences"

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement the sample code provided by Amazon for connecting to DynamoDb. The first step is the initialization of clients and Amazon says to define credentials in a constants class and use them as such:

```
private void initClients() {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentials = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            context,
            Constants.ACCOUNT_ID,
            Constants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            Constants.UNAUTH_ROLE_ARN,
            null,
            Regions.US_EAST_1);
```

When I executed the code, I get the following:
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences

I then created a SharedPreferences file and put the credentials in it and still got the same errors. Does anyone know what and where the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider is looking for in this case?

Comment: Is it the only requirement? I think it has 3rd party stuff that you might have not placed yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That message isn't an error - just a notification that you don't have credentials yet. Don't worry about creating the SharedPreferences file, that is handled internally by Cognito. Once you do any operation via the credentials provider that requires it to get credentials, it will automatically cache them internally.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answer given by Viktor Burmaka, I want to point out the Amazon guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html) is a bit incomplete.

It says to add the line:

```
<service
  android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
  android:enabled="true" />
```

To the `androidmanifest.xml` file

**HOWEVER**

It didn't mention that line needs to be nested within the `<application></application>` tag like this:

```
<application>
    ...
    <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
    ...
</application>
```

I found this via the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Which says:

```
<service>
SYNTAX:
<service android:description="string resource"
         android:directBootAware=["true" | "false"]
         android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
         android:exported=["true" | "false"]
         android:icon="drawable resource"
         android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
         android:label="string resource"
         android:name="string"
         android:permission="string"
         android:process="string" >
    . . .
</service>
CONTAINED IN:
<application>
```

### NETWORK_STATE Permission

Android Studio required me to add this permission also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Check yours Manifest file, please. I use s3 and I had the same when missed

```
 <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
android:enabled="true" />
```